# How to use WC_Email_Customer_Note on Frontend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have made a custom file with my own codes where the functions and processes are almost the same with the Edit Order Details form found in the admin side.

Everything's working as expected except for the adding of notes and the user click 'Note to customer'. It's supposed to send an email to the customer stating the new not. I found this class

> WC_Email_Customer_Note

in Woocommerce documentation but I'm lost on how to do that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Eli

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you rephrase or elaborate? Maybe share some of the code you've written.

Comment: I'd like to use the class WC_Email_Customer_Note from Woocommerce. Do you have any idea how to do it or can you point me to a good tutorial for this? My goal is to be able to send an email to the customer when I add a note. It's working in the admin side but I'm trying to do it on frontend.

Comment: That email is triggered on the `woocommerce_new_customer_note_notification` hook. So you probably need to fire that hook in your front end. `do_action('woocommerce_new_customer_note_notification');`  or it might also be possible to attach the trigger function to a different hook.